# Return the next right node

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

Given a binary tree, return the next right node. This question is attributed to [GeeksForGeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-next-right-node-of-a-given-key/).

For example, consider the following Binary Tree. Output for 2 is 6, output for 4 is 5. Output for 10, 6 and 5 is NULL.

```
              10
           /      \
          2         6
       /   \         \ 
     8      4          5
```

Looking for code-review, optimizations and best practices.

```
class TreeNodeRightMost {
    TreeNodeRightMost left;
    int item;
    TreeNodeRightMost right;

    TreeNodeRightMost(TreeNodeRightMost left, int item, TreeNodeRightMost right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.item = item;
        this.right = right;
    }
}


class BinaryTree {

    private TreeNodeRightMost root;

    public BinaryTree(List<Integer> items) {
        create(items);
    }

    private void create (List<Integer> items) {        
        root = new TreeNodeRightMost(null, items.get(0), null);

        final Queue<TreeNodeRightMost> queue = new LinkedList<TreeNodeRightMost>();
        queue.add(root);

        final int half = items.size() / 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < half; i++) {
            if (items.get(i) != null) {
                final TreeNodeRightMost current = queue.poll();
                final int left = 2 * i + 1;
                final int right = 2 * i + 2;

                if (items.get(left) != null) {
                    current.left = new TreeNodeRightMost(null, items.get(left), null);
                    queue.add(current.left);
                }
                if (right < items.size() && items.get(right) != null) {
                    current.right = new TreeNodeRightMost(null, items.get(right), null);
                    queue.add(current.right);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public TreeNodeRightMost getRoot() {
        return root;
    }
}



public final class FindRightMost {

    private FindRightMost() {}

    /**
     * If two nodes with the same values are present then the node with least depth on the left most side
     * is considered.
     */
    public static Integer findRight (BinaryTree tree, int val) {
        final TreeNodeRightMost root = tree.getRoot();

        if (root == null) throw new IllegalStateException(" empty tree is not permitted");

        Queue<TreeNodeRightMost> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        Queue<TreeNodeRightMost> queueNext = new LinkedList<>();
        queue.add(root);

        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            TreeNodeRightMost node = queue.poll();

            if (node.item == val) {
                if (queue.size() > 0) {
                    return queue.poll().item;
                } else {
                    return null; 
                }
            }


            if (node.left != null) queueNext.add(node.left);
            if (node.right != null) queueNext.add(node.right);

            if (queue.isEmpty()) {
                queue = queueNext;
                queueNext = new LinkedList<>();
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Dude !! your input was not present in the tree");
    }
}

public class FindRightMostTest {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        /**
         * Simple tree with just 1 node
         */
        BinaryTree btree1 = new BinaryTree(Arrays.asList(1));
        assertNull(FindRightMost.findRight(btree1, 1));
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        /** 
         *        10
         *      /    \
         *     5       18
         *    / \     / \
         *   4   6   17   19
         */
        BinaryTree btree2 = new BinaryTree(Arrays.asList(10, 5, 18, 4, 6, 17, 19));
        assertEquals(18, (int)FindRightMost.findRight(btree2, 5));
        assertNull(FindRightMost.findRight(btree2, 18));
        assertEquals(6,  (int)FindRightMost.findRight(btree2, 4));
        assertEquals(17, (int)FindRightMost.findRight(btree2, 6));
        assertEquals(19, (int)FindRightMost.findRight(btree2,17));
        assertNull(FindRightMost.findRight(btree2, 19));
    }


    @Test
    public void test3() {
        /**
         *               1
         *           /      \
         *      null          2
         *     /   \         /   \
         *   null  null    null    3
         */
        BinaryTree btree3 = new BinaryTree(Arrays.asList(1, null, 2, null, null, null, 3));
        assertNull(FindRightMost.findRight(btree3, 1));
        assertNull(FindRightMost.findRight(btree3, 2));
        assertNull(FindRightMost.findRight(btree3, 3));
    }

    @Test
    public void test4() {
        /**
         *                 4
         *             /     \ 
         *          2          null
         *       /   \        /    \
         *      1    null  null    null
         */
        BinaryTree btree4 = new BinaryTree(Arrays.asList(4, 2, null, 1, null));
        assertNull(FindRightMost.findRight(btree4, 2));
        assertNull(FindRightMost.findRight(btree4, 1));
    }

    @Test
    public void test5() {

        /**
         *             1
         *     2            3      
         *  4     null   null    7 
         * 
         */
        BinaryTree btree5 = new BinaryTree(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, null, null, 7));
        assertNull(FindRightMost.findRight(btree5, 1));
        assertEquals(3, (int)FindRightMost.findRight(btree5, 2));
        assertNull(FindRightMost.findRight(btree5, 3));
        assertEquals(7, (int)FindRightMost.findRight(btree5, 4));
        assertNull(FindRightMost.findRight(btree5, 7));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just reviewing the `findRight()` method since many of the Node and other constructs have been reviewed in other questions of yours, and there's not much changed since then...

> ```
> public static Integer findRight (BinaryTree tree, int val) {
>     final TreeNodeRightMost root = tree.getRoot();
>
>     if (root == null) throw new IllegalStateException(" empty tree is not permitted");
>
>     Queue<TreeNodeRightMost> queue = new LinkedList<>();
>     Queue<TreeNodeRightMost> queueNext = new LinkedList<>();
>     queue.add(root);
>
>     while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
>         TreeNodeRightMost node = queue.poll();
>
>         if (node.item == val) {
>             if (queue.size() > 0) {
>                 return queue.poll().item;
>             } else {
>                 return null; 
>             }
>         }
>
>
>         if (node.left != null) queueNext.add(node.left);
>         if (node.right != null) queueNext.add(node.right);
>
>         if (queue.isEmpty()) {
>             queue = queueNext;
>             queueNext = new LinkedList<>();
>         }
>     }
>
>     throw new IllegalArgumentException("Dude !! your input was not present in the tree");
> }
> ```

Your code takes an `int` argument, but returns an `Integer`. These things have been discussed before. Your actual nodes contain an int, so you need to find a better solution to the mixing of primitive and Object types.

There is a simpler way to do this using a single queue, and adding a null value to the queue to mark the end-of-line for the tree. This saves having to swap the `queue` and `queueNext` instances.

You throw an exception with a space as the first character, and it's not well formatted.... `if (root == null) throw new IllegalStateException(" empty tree is not permitted");`... additionally, it is a 1-liner statement without using `{}` braces. These are things that have been said before, but don't seem to be sinking in. You use 1-liner if-blocks for the left and right adds as well.

The 'Dude!' exception is cheesy, and not relevant.

Consider the alternate code:

```
public static Integer findRight (BinaryTree tree, Integer val) {
    final TreeNodeRightMost root = tree.getRoot();

    if (root == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Empty trees are not permitted");
    }

    Queue<TreeNodeRightMost> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    queue.add(root);
    queue.add(null);

    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {

        TreeNodeRightMost node = queue.poll();
        if (node == null) {
            // reached the end of a level.
            if (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                queue.add(null);
            }
        } else {

            if (val.equals(node.item)) {
                 TreeNodeRightMost ret = queue.poll();
                 return ret != null ? ret.item : null;
            }

            if (node.left != null) {
                queue.add(node.left);
            }
            if (node.right != null) {
                queue.add(node.right);
            }

        }
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Your input was not in the tree");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A minor bug: You get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` for an empty list in `BinaryTree.create(List<Integer> items)`. You don't have a comment stating you need to input a list containing at least something. Consider returning `IllegalArgumentException` and adding a comment.